# Should favor "_this" instead of "self" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In [Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/es5), they mentioned "When saving a reference to this use _this."

```
// bad
function() {
  var self = this;
  return function() {
    console.log(self);
  };
}

// bad
function() {
  var that = this;
  return function() {
    console.log(that);
  };
}

// good
function() {
  var _this = this;
  return function() {
    console.log(_this);
  };
}
```

However, I read few books mentioned "self" is good. Like in [AngularJS: Up and Running](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033486.do).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('notesApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', [function () {
      var self = this;
      self.message = 'Hello ';
      self.changeMessage = function () {
        self.message = 'Goodbye';
      };
    }]);
</script>
```

So, could any one tell me the reason to use "_this" instead of "self"?

Comment: 'Use a leading underscore _ when naming private properties.'

Comment: This is just the naming of a variable, there's no real impact.

Comment: It's called a style guide for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use `self` as it is already in use as another pointer to the `window` object. See here (part way down page) for an example of using `self` like a variable (without needing to prefix it as `window.self`): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/self

Comment: Thanks, got it. So the suggestion is that avoid use `self` as it will overwrite the variable.

Comment: Yes, that's right, it's not a reserved word in JavaScript, but it's a variable inside the browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is just personal preference. However, it's best to only use one option inside a project's codebase. So don't use _this in one function block, then that or self in the other..

Answer (score 1):

As noted by others, this is purely a coding style preference. I would offer a suggestion: If your team's code base is interested in continuing to use *lexical scoping* for `this`, then consider using **ES6**'s [fat arrow](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#arrows) function instead to avoid creating an unnecessary variable.

This of course all depends if your project is ready to implement ES6 features.